# Linq c# query to join two many to many relationship

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, ef-core-3.0

here i  have a group containing many users and assets ,i want list of assets linked to a single user.
What is the best way of using linq.

```
 public class Asset
    { 
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<GroupToAssets> GroupToAssets { get; set; }
    }

 public class User: IdentityUser
    {
       public virtual ICollection<GroupToUsers> GroupToUsers { get; set; }
    }

 public class GroupToAssets
    {     
        public Guid GroupId { get; set; }
        public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
        public Guid AssetId { get; set; }
        public virtual Asset  Asset { get; set; }
    }

 public class GroupToUsers
    {   
        public Guid GroupId { get; set; }
        public virtual  Group Group { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no attempt was shown to solve the problem.

Comment: i think i have cracked it please see the answer and improve it

Answer (score 0):

I think the following linq satisfy my case don't know if there is a better method

```
   var Groups =
 await _Context.Groups.Where(x => x.GroupToUsers.Any(d => d.UserId == UserId && d.GroupId == x.Id)).ToListAsync();
    var assets =
 await _Context.GroupToAssets.Where(x => Groups.Contains(x.Group)).Select(x => new { x.Asset }).Distinct().ToListAsync();
```